# How to use attribute as image name with the SYMBOL keyword?

Tags: symbology, mapserver

I have a set of PNG images contained in a server folder that I wish to use as point symbols. The symbol should be defined by the attribute `symb_name`. So in my MAP file, I'd like to do something like this:

```
CLASS
    EXPRESSION (xxx)
    STYLE
        SYMBOL '../symbols/images/' + "[symb_name]" + '.png'
        SIZE 10
    END
END
```

I just don't seem to be able to concatenate or include the image file name correctly in the SYMBOL keyword. Is it possible, and what would be the correct syntax? (I'm using a fairly old version of Mapserver, 5.2.1.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the trick myself to accomplish what I want. Like this:

```
DATA ... (select ..., '../symbols/images/' || sname || '.png' symb_name, ...)
```

`CLASS
    EXPRESSION (xxx)
    STYLE
        SYMBOL [symb_name]
        SIZE 10
    END
END`